# Rose plot in ggplot2 error: aesthetics must be either length 1 or same as the data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a rose plot in ggplot2. I have previously made one with the following code, but I have substituted different data in and its now giving me an error. Does anyone see something I don't?
Thanks

Here is the data:

```
> d <- structure(list(Angle = c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 
+ 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 
+ 230, 240, 250, 260, 270, 280, 290, 300, 310, 320, 330, 340, 350, 360
+ ), Frequency = c(0.3, 1.5, 1.6, 1.9, 2.4, 3.1, 9.6, 5.6, 5.8, 5.6, 8.8, 4, 9, 7.5, 4.6, 2.5, 1.3, 3.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.3, 2.2, 1.1, 0.5, 1.9, 2.2, 1.1, 0.3, 0, 1.7, 1.6, 2.8, 0.7, 0.7, 1.9, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Angle", "Frequency"
+ ), row.names = c(NA, 36L), class = "data.frame")
> str(d)
```

And this is the code I previously used to create the rose plot:

```
> library(ggplot2)
> ggplot(d, aes(x = Angle, y = Frequency)) +
+   coord_polar(theta = "x", start = -pi/36) +
+   geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
+   scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 360, 60))
```

The exact error I receive is:

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data
>   (36): x, y

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be caused by the fact that your data has 37 entries, but your row.names are set to go to 36, causing R to make some guesses. If you change `36L` to `37L` in the data specification (under row.names), this works as entered.